# _proto_ and prototype are not equal to each other

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

I was learning object-oriented programming on Javascript from a course. I did exactly what the instructor showed us to write, but the answer of mine is different than him. My "*proto*" is not equal to the function "prototype".

[Heres the comparison image between my result and the instructor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWPfm.jpg)

Comment: My neuronal image analysis tells me you wrote `__proto__` with only one underscore on each side. That being said, `__proto__` is a deprecated feature, which can stop working at any point in time, without prior warning. Also, next time, post the related code as text please, to avoid getting instantly downvoted.

Comment: Use [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) isntead of `__proto__`. The latter is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

In your version, you're using a single underscore on both sides => `_proto_`

You should be using two underscores on both sides => `__proto__`

Comment: i used _ proto _. where will I put another underscore?

Comment: I've edited the answer to hopefully be more clear - in case that isn't enough, your very last command `elie._proto_ === Person.prototype` would need another underscore on both sides of the `_proto_`

Comment: As @adiga also says, you should perhaps use `Object.getPrototypeof` if you were doing similar in the future
That code would look like this:
`Object.getPrototypeOf(elie) === Person.prototype`